# How to fix the error arising System.AccessViolationException?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle10g

Windows Form application using C# Visual Studio 2017
connected to Oracle Database 10g

I've tried many options listed on stack overflow, but they did not match my requirements

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = MSDAORA; Data source=XE; User ID=db1;Password=xyz;Unicode=True");
    OleDbDataAdapter x = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM USER_LOGIN WHERE USERNAME = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and PASSWORD = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable d = new DataTable();
    x.Fill(d);
```

Expected Result is that it will fetch the data from the table using adapter x and fill it into datatable d.

But when the method is evoked, this error is shown at x.fill(d);
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'